# How do I get rid of extra spaces in html rendered by Haml & Ruby?

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm trying to format a simple sentence that reads like this:

[image: want]

When my haml looks like this:

```
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} x,
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} y, 
    and
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} z.
```

I get

[image: undesired link on comma]

When my haml looks a little different::

```
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} x
    ,
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} y
    , and
    %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'} z
    .
```

I get

[image]

...and the spaces look wrong.

How can I make it look the way I want?

I want it to look like

[image: want]

...with the commas and period not being links and no weird extra spaces.

Comment: try it using link_to tag, added answer for the same

Comment: Did you know this trick? [Whitespace removal](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).

Comment: Do you really want a comma after y? A comma and a 'and' does not make sense

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: Haml isn’t very good at things like this, see http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation

Comment: @matt thanx and sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will help

```
= link_to "x", "Your-url",  target: "_blank"
,
= link_to "y", "Your-url",  target: "_blank"
= "and"
= link_to "z", "Your-url",  target: "_blank"
```

Comment: Thank you but, unfortunately, when I try that.. I still get the undesired space before the comma.

Comment: please right click on any link element and inspect it on browser and check the width of a tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following as well

```
= "<a href='link' target='_blank'>x</a>, <a href='link' target='_blank'>y</a> and <a href='link' target='_blank'>z</a>".html_safe
```

Comment: Thanks! I will save the html insertion option for tomorrow. If I can't get the haml to do it using @teoreda 's instructions I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write link like:

```
= ("#{link_to('x', 'link', target: '_blank')}, #{link_to('y', 'link', target: '_blank')}, and #{link_to('z', 'link', target: '_blank')}.").html_safe
```

Also you can replace 'link' to link like root_path and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, you could try
[`Helpers#succeed`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#succeed-instance_method)

e.g.

```
= succeed ',' do
  %a{:href=>"link"}x
= succeed ',' do
  %a{:href=>"link"}y
```

Comment: I gave this solution before... You should read the other solutions before answering...

Comment: You edited your older, totally different given solution while I was typing this solution. Couldn't have known :)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** due to my misunderstanding I gave you a not correct solution, this could be what you need:

You should use

> succeed

from the [haml helper:](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#succeed-instance_method)

```
= succeed ',' do
 %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'}x
= succeed ',' do
 %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'}y
= succeed '.' do
 %a{:href => "link", :target=> '_blank'}z
```

Comment: ...but then the commas will be links, right? I don't want them to be links.

Comment: oh wait... without the space after the brace. Trying it.

Comment: I still need the commas to not be links and the only way to do that, that I know, is to put them on the next line.. which adds space around them.

Comment: I will try it. I also updated the question to have illustrations.

Comment: ... either I'm typing my haml wrong or what you are suggesting in the edit still causes extra spaces to get rendered.

Comment: You are totally right... Sorry for my misunderstanding. Now I think that I understand correctly your question and I edited the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I keep getting syntax errors about the tabs and indentation. I'll try tomorrow. Good night.

Comment: just wanted to let you know I can't work on this until the evening (in California). Thanks so much for your advice!! I'm definitely going to try it.